# Mapping pads to broken guitar chords with velocity sensitivity for live performance

Tags: guitar, chords, midi, live, cubase

I am a complete rookie to music theory nor do I know how to play a keyboard or guitar. I like to sing and perform therefore I need help to execute this, if at all it is possible:

[Something along these lines.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vwYw2zMLyGU)

I plan to buy a **MIDI keyboard with velocity sensitive pads (Akai MPK mini/play) for live performances** (I can connect it to a laptop on stage). I want to play certain set of **guitar chords** when I hit the pads and depending in how fast or hard I hit the pad, the speed and volume of the chord should also change (like broken chords on a guitar). Perhaps even add some base that corresponds to the velocity (Ambitiously).

**Is something like this possible?** perhaps with software like CuBase?

If so, please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me what sound you want, but there are software samplers such as Kontakt, Directwave, FL Studio's FPC, and more, which let you assign every note/pad AND every velocity to a specific recording (and you can make the recording loop, as well).  It will be a bit tedious to program in 10 different velocities for 24 different chords- that is 240 audio files to create and assign. If you're willing to do that, though, you can make the chords differ across the velocity range in any way you wish.

If using a software instrument with pre-made strum patterns, you may be able to do this much faster by simply linking velocity to the strum pattern parameters.  I imagine that most DAWs have a way to do this.  Try searching "(DAW name) link note velocity to parameter".  You can also link parameters to mod wheels on your controller, if applicable.